# How can I retrieve profile images when using GridFS and multer

Tags: node.js, express, image-uploading, multer

One of the features of the app I am building allows uses to upload profile pictures like on facebook, twitter and quora.

It seems that multer is for handling information uploaded from the form and it's supposed to stored in a file storage system using GRidFS. I have completed the file upload part.

How do i store the images so that they can be accessed by the user?

```js
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

  // image upload route
app.post('/photos/upload',upload.single('avatar'),       function(req, res) {
      console.log(req.user.img);
      console.log(req.file);
      var user = req.user;
      user.img = req.file;

      user.save(function(err) {
          res.redirect('/profile');
      });
```

Comment: I have not use GridFS, but I think that you will have to convert the file to base64, and then save it to a document (field) that support blob types.

Comment: what do you use when you want to upload images to mongodb?@hosar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this without using GridFs. Just used multer to upload to an upload folder and saved the path to the file in the mongo collection for each user that uploads an image.

```js
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb){
    cb(null, 'public/uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname + '-' +Date.now())
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('avatar');

// to post the path to the database.

app.post('/photos/upload', function(req, res) {
        upload(req, res, function(err) {


            if (err) {
                res.redirect('/profile')
                return res.send("Error uploading file");
            } else if (req.file == null) {

                res.redirect('/profile')
            } else {

                if ((facebook != null) && (local != null)) {
                    User.findOne({

                        'facebook.email': facebook
                    }, function(err, user) {
                        if (err) {
                            return done(err);
                        }

                        console.log(user)
                        user.img = req.file.path

                        user.save(function(err) {
                            if (err) {
                                throw err;
                            }


                        });

                    });
                } else if ((facebook != null) && (local == null)) {
                    User.findOne({

                        'facebook.email': facebook
                    }, function(err, user) {
                        if (err) {
                            return done(err);
                        }

                        console.log(user)
                        user.img = req.file.path

                        user.save(function(err) {
                            if (err) {
                                throw err;
                            }


                        });

                    });
                } else if ((facebook == null) && (local != null))  {
                        User.findOne({

                            'local.email': local
                        }, function(err, user) {
                            if (err) {
                                return done(err);
                            }

                            console.log(user)
                            user.img = req.file.path

                            user.save(function(err) {
                                if (err) {
                                    throw err;
                                }


                            });

                        });
                    }
                }

            })
            res.redirect('/profile');

        });
```